# Puppeteer not correctly handling XPath

Tags: xpath, puppeteer

Given the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="first">
      <div id="sub">
        <a href="test.html">test</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="second">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

According to the Chrome Developer tools, the XPath to the "test" link is

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/a
```

However, when I do

```
const selector ="/html/body/div[1]/div/a";

await page.waitForXPath(selector);
console.log("after waiting for selector -> selector was found");
```

it never passes the `await page.waitForXPath(selector);` line.
Can anyone explain why and how I have to modify the XPath?

I did some experimenting and waiting for an xpath works with `/html/body/div[1]` but not anymore with `/html/body/div[1]/div`, also not with `/html/body/div[1]/div[1]`

I am using puppeteer-core@5.3.1 and Chrome 85.0.4183.121 on Ubuntu.

**Update**:

Just to make sure my XPath is correct, I tested it in the Chrome Devtools console, where it works fine:

```
$x("/html/body/div[1]/div/a")
[a] <-- returns expected result
```

Still can't understand why it's not working with Puppeteer.

Comment: What's your expected output? The link (`test.html`) or the text (`test`)?

Comment: Actually I want both

Comment: I just saved your html as a separate file locally and then open the file in browser. I was able to find the element by selector `/html/body/div[1]/div/a` and the console.log was printed. Maybe you have some real site example where it can be verified?

Comment: @Lanken that's exactly the issue I have. It works in Chrome Devtools / console, but not within Puppeteer

Comment: I was mean, that i was able to get the console.log in the puppeteer script https://www.codepile.net/raw/oqQmxeqX.js

Comment: were you able to find a solution?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't remember how this went out ):

Answer (score 1):

Try these xpath expressions and see if they work:

```
//div/a/text()
```

should return (using the html in your question) `test`. And

```
//div/a/@href
```

should return

```
test.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but I really need absolute paths to make sure that my xpath is unique (the example given is just a reduced testcase to demonstrate the problem)

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf Got it, though - obviously - I can't give you an absolute xpath without the full html. If it helps, I can give you absolute xpath for the example html.

Comment: I unfortunately can't provide the "real" HTML, but that shouldn't matter as the reduced test case has the same issue. I took the absolute XPath from the Chrome Devtools `/html/body/div[1]/div/a` It works fine in the Chrome console, but not in Puppeteer. That's the issue I have and don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It waits until `<a href="test.html">test</a>` shows up and return the value.

```js
  const selector = await "/html/body/div[1]/div/a";
  await page.waitForXPath(selector);

  const href = await page.$x(selector);
  const href_value = await page.evaluate((...href) => {
    return href.map(e => e.href);
  }, ...href);

  await console.log(href_value);
```